# Busy box, Run C, python or Perl programs

Tags: python, linux, perl, gcc, busybox

All I have is bourne shell and busy box.
Is there any way to run a python script or compile a c program or any languages like perl ..

like 
`busybox python eatmemory.py 100M`

or

`busybox gcc eatmemory.c`

What I need is to create a process which will consume a specific amount of memory. and test the performance.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964799/write-a-bash-shell-script-that-consumes-a-constant-amount-of-ram-for-a-user-defi

Comment: What system do you have? Have you installed Linux on your laptop/desktop (first, to learn Linux, and second, to cross-compile)? You could also consider using tinycc (i.e. `tcc` which compiles quickly C code into unoptimized machine code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is

> Does `busybox` come with a `python` interpreter or C compiler?

then the answer is no.

If it is

> Is there a way to write a script that will run under `busybox`' `ash` shell which will just allocate some memory for me?

then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4972220/612462) answer, as suggested by Andrey.

Answer (score 1):

a simple perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# store and validate the command line parameter
my $mb = $ARGV[0];
unless ( defined $mb and $mb =~ /^\d+$/ and $mb >= 1)  {
    die "Usage: $0 <occupy MB>\nEx: $0 100 - occupies 100 MB memory\n"
}
# convert it to bytes.
my $b = $mb * 1024 * 1024;

my $memfile;

# open in-memory file, and seek to size specified to get memory from OS.
open MEM, '>', \$memfile;
seek MEM, $b - 1, 0;
print MEM 'A';
close MEM;
printf "$mb MB memory is occupied, press ENTER to release: "; <STDIN>;

# till here the memory is occupied by this program.
undef $memfile;
printf "Memory released";
```

assuming you name the script `eat_memory.pl`, start it by:

```
perl eat_memory.pl 150
```

where the 150 represents megabytes

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot run perl on the machine, I can use only busybox.
And I found no way to run c or python or perl program using busybox

Comment: @AbhishekLal If you can't run Perl, why do you have it as a tag on the question?

Comment: @Brad Gilbert I added it because of my doubt "Does busybox come with a python interpreter, perl or C compiler?"

Comment: @AbhishekLal [Busybox is a single executable that has a bunch of Unix utilities built-in.](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) The only programming language that it comes with is a shell language.