# How to generate a memory shortage using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, esxi

I need to write a bash script that would consume a maximum of RAM of my ESXi and potentially generate a memory shortage.

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964799/write-a-bash-shell-script-that-consumes-a-constant-amount-of-ram-for-a-user-defi) and try to run the given script several times so that I can consume more thant 500Mb of RAM.

However I get a "sh: out of memory" error (of course) and I'd like to know if there is any possibility to configuration the amount of memory allocated to my shell ?

- Note1 : Another requirement is that I cannot enter a VM a run a greedy task.
- Note2 : I tried to script the creation of greedy new VMs with huge RAM however I cannot get to ESXi state where there is a shortage of memory.
- Note3 : I cannot use a C compiler and I only have very limited python library.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: make a ramdisk ( https://wiki.debian.org/ramfs ) and fill it with a large file.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the "mount" command on my ESXi server.

Comment: ESXi is not a based on a kernel I can modify...

Comment: If a fork bomb works then the best solution is to launch a massive amount of processes and disable your swap (if you have one). To find out if it works: `:(){ :|:& };:` but do this ONLY IF YOU ARE PREPARED TO SWITCH YOUR SERVER OFF AFTER TESTING THIS !!

Comment: I cannot launch a fork bomb directly on my server, ESXi prevent it.

Answer (score 13):

From an earlier answer of mine: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254976/30731

> If you have basic GNU tools (`head` and `tail`) or BusyBox on Linux, you can do this to **fill a certain amount of free memory**:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | tail
>
> # Protip: use $((1024**3*7)) to calculate 7GiB easily
> </dev/zero head -c $((1024**3*7)) | tail
> ```
>
> This works because tail needs to keep the current line in memory, in case it turns out to be the last line. The line, read from `/dev/zero` which outputs only null bytes and no newlines, will be infinitely long, but is limited by `head` to `BYTES` bytes, thus `tail` will use only that much memory. For a more precise amount, you will need to check how much RAM `head` and `tail` itself use on your system and subtract that.
>
> To just quickly **run out of RAM completely**, you can remove the limiting `head` part:
>
> ```
> tail /dev/zero
> ```
>
> If you want to also **add a duration**, this can be done quite easily in `bash` (will not work in `sh`):
>
> ```
> cat <( </dev/zero head -c BYTES) <(sleep SECONDS) | tail
> ```
>
> The `<(command)` thing seems to be little known but is often extremely useful, more info on it here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html
>
> Then for the use of `cat`: `cat` will wait for inputs to complete until exiting, and by keeping one of the pipes open, it will keep `tail` alive.
>
> If you have `pv` and want to **slowly increase RAM use**:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | pv -L BYTES_PER_SEC | tail
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c $((1024**3)) | pv -L $((1024**2)) | tail
> ```
>
> Will use up to a gigabyte at a rate of a megabyte per second. As an added bonus, **`pv` will show you the current rate of use and the total use so far**. Of course this can also be done with previous variants:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | pv | tail
> ```
>
> Just inserting the `| pv |` part will show you the current status (throughput and total by default).
>
> ---
>
> Credits to [falstaff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200982/how-to-generate-a-memory-shortage-using-bash-script/34755981#comment78484190_34755981) for contributing a variant that is even simpler and more broadly compatible (like with BusyBox).

Comment: This does not seem to work with a busybox grep. I found this solution, but it just consumes memory unbound (which was what I was looking for) `tail /dev/zero`

Comment: @falstaff Works for me too on Debian with GNU tools. Seems your solution is more universal, nice find! Do you mind if I incorporate your solution into my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Bash has the `ulimit` command, which can be used to set the size of the virtual memory which may be used by a bash process and the processes started by it.

There are two limits, a hard limit and a soft limit. You can lower both limits, but only raise the soft limit up to the hard limit.
`ulimit -S -v unlimited` sets the virtual memory size to unlimited (if the hard limit allows this).
If there is a hard limit set (see `ulimit -H -v`), check any initialisation scripts for lines setting it.