# how to eat up all the android memory in an android application?

Tags: android, memory, root

recently, I am testing the performance of swap partition for android device. I need to eat up all the memory in a test application(can has root authority), so that some pages can swap out.
how can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to use ADB and have busybox you may be able to use a shell script that allocates memory until it's exhausted.

refer to [Write a bash shell script that consumes a constant amount of RAM for a user defined time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964799/write-a-bash-shell-script-that-consumes-a-constant-amount-of-ram-for-a-user-defi)

ripped from that answer:

```
#!/bin/ash

echo "Provide sleep time in the form of NUMBER[SUFFIX]"
echo "   SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (default), 'm' for minutes,"
echo "   'h' for hours, or 'd' for days."
read -p "> " delay

echo "begin allocating memory..."
for index in $(seq 1000); do
    value=$(seq -w -s '' $index $(($index + 100000)))
    eval array$index=$value
done
echo "...end allocating memory"

echo "sleeping for $delay"
sleep $delay
```

Answer (score 1):

load a bunch of bitmaps into memory, without weak references

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.someresource, null);

or if you want to load from the disk

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filenamestring);

Comment: very instructive, I was trying to use [new]

Comment: I'm pretty sure they want to use all the memory in the system, not just by the app.  this will give an out of memory exception when it hits the app's limits.

Comment: do you know how many posts are out there for "Out of Memory Error" on this issue ?

Comment: I don't think the system will let him eat up all the memory in the system. just for the app itself. Depending on the device it can vary from 40 megs to 1gb

Comment: I agree, which means this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: using adb, can I achieve this goal? I have busybox @JohnBoker