# Write program consumes certain amount of memory

Tags: bash, memory

In my recently experiment, I need a program that consumes certain amount of memory. I want to implement it in bash script, say, I want this script runs as a daemon and consumes around 200mb physical memory. How to design this script?

If it's possible, I hope it can be run without permission.

Comment: did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964799/write-a-bash-shell-script-that-consumes-a-constant-amount-of-ram-for-a-user-defi) SO?

Comment: While it's possible to "allocate" a certain amount of memory using shell scripts, it's not possible to force it to be *physical* memory (as in locked to actual RAM) in a shell script. There probably are system calls that can do that but those are not available through normal commands.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is what you looking for

```
mntroot rw
 cd /dev
 while : 
 do 
        dd > /dev/null 2>&1 if=/dev/zero of=myfile1 count=20000 bs=1024 # use 200MB ram
        usleep 1 
        rm myfile1

 done
```

Comment: You can also use `count=1 bs=200M`

Comment: Thanks JID thanks for the advice, @hakunami did you make it work?

Comment: @Ethaan Since I am working on a distributed system, and many workers may run this script on the same node. I am wondering if there is any write conflict possible in my case?

Comment: Well i was never in that situation, but it shouldn't, i will be laying if a tell you yes or not, it will be nice if you test it and tell me if some issue appears.

Comment: its to mount the fyle on the system root and make it accessible

Comment: @Ethaan Some questions want to be clear. 1. seems I need `sudo` to run script ? 2. I use `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` to make `/` read and write, am I right? 3. I use `pmap` to check memory usage, but all numbers are 0, something wrong?

Comment: This script needs `sudo` to run, it doesn't work without it.

And on some system like Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, `mntroot rw` is not avaliable, for going into root you can use `cd ~`