# Simulate Memory Leak in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, memory-leaks, stress-testing

I need to run a bash command to simulate a memory leak in Linux to test my web server performance. I have used Stree-ng tool to stress memory, but I noticed that CPU usage reaches 100% when this command starts running. Now I have two question:

1. In reality, a usual memory related anomaly in web servers, has this pattern of increasing both CPU and Memory or just Memory?
2. Is there a way that I can increase memory usage without a significant increase of CPU?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a bash shell script that consumes a constant amount of RAM for a user defined time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964799/write-a-bash-shell-script-that-consumes-a-constant-amount-of-ram-for-a-user-defi)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this one too, but again I see a high increase in CPU! The point is that I'm not sure if this will be a real pattern for memory related faults or not.